# What is wrong with the mysql clause

Tags: php, mysql

**TABLE bcompany**

```
companyID | cName | ...
```

I have the input field, where user searches for the records including the "input" characters:

```
<input type="text" class="bigblack" name="srch" />
```

**PHP:**

```
$req="%".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['srch'])."%";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT companyID, cName FROM bcompany WHERE
companyID OR cName LIKE $req ORDER BY companyID LIMIT 10");

OR

$query = mysql_query("SELECT companyID, cName FROM bcompany WHERE
companyID,cName LIKE $req ORDER BY companyID LIMIT 10");
```

Both queries return an error:

> mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource....

There is probably something wrong with the MYSQL SELECT.

Can you please help me solve this out?

Thanks in advance :)

Rest of the code:

```
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {


    echo $res["companyID"];
    echo $res["cName"]."<br>";



}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You query should be:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT companyID, cName FROM bcompany WHERE
companyID LIKE '$req' OR cName LIKE '$req' ORDER BY companyID LIMIT 10");
```

Here are the docs for MySQL LIKE:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Alternatively you could use the MySQL REGEXP in place of LIKE in your queries.

It looks like mysql_fetch_array is griping when you call it because the query is incorrect and not producing a result which mysql_fetch_array can use.

Answer (score 2):

You need to surround your string with quotes:

```
mysql_query("SELECT companyID, cName FROM bcompany WHERE companyID,cName LIKE '$req' ORDER BY companyID LIMIT 10");
```

Should work.

Ah, missed this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT companyID, cName FROM bcompany WHERE companyID LIKE '$req' OR cName LIKE '$req' ORDER BY companyID LIMIT 10");
```

You may want to change the OR to AND.

Answer (score 2):

From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.

As such the problem you have is that `$query`is false but in your (unshown) code you aren't checking for that.

The cause is the query, or queries, you have are invalid, taking the first one:

```
SELECT
    companyID, cName 
FROM 
    bcompany
WHERE
    companyID OR cName LIKE $req
ORDER BY
    companyID
LIMIT 10
```

This is not a valid query, you would need:

```
SELECT
    companyID, cName 
FROM 
    bcompany
WHERE
    companyID LIKE "$req" OR cName LIKE "$req"
ORDER BY
    companyID
LIMIT 10
```

You can help identify problems like this by running the queries directly against the db (open a terminal window and `mysql -uname -ppass db` etc.), and not via php. Doing so with either of the queries in the question will spit out:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that cor...

Making it more obvious where the error is.

Comment: Thank you for the additional explanation :)